# org agenda not loading org-agenda-files funkiness

Tags: init-file, org-agenda

My config file has the following funkiness:
I have the line `(setq org-agenda-files '("~/org/tktodos.org" ))`
followed by the line `(org-agenda nil "a")`.

When my org file loads, I can see my todos in my agenda. If I then press C-h v org-agenda-files, the value is set to nil, so if I exit and reopen, none of my todos will show.

If I move the line `(setq org-agenda-files '("~/org/tktodos.org" ))` to the very end of the config file, nothing changes.

If I re-evaluate the line `(setq org-agenda-files '("~/org/tktodos.org" ))`, org-agenda works again. What's going on?

Answer (score 0):

So the best "temporary" (may not be temporary xD ) solution I have is to just customize the org-agenda-files variable and save it for all future sessions. Not my fave, but ya gotta do what ya gotta do xP